# XAML Theme Brushes - Switching Dynamically, cursor doesn't change

Tags: xaml, textbox, windows-runtime

First Off, I found this extremely useful page on theme brushes:
http://metro.excastle.com/xaml-system-brushes

So Roughly, on startup for WinRT/XAML I am setting my theme brush for a textbox in a stylesheet:
Foreground = TextBoxDisabledForegroundThemeBrush
Background = TextBoxDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush

Which at run time makes the textbox appear as: white border, transparent background and grey text.  Which I was hoping it would make it transparent, white border and white text.

On my Tapped event, I change the textbox to:
Foreground = TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush
Background = TextBoxButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush

Which is supposed to be black background, white text and white border.  Which seems right, but the cursor is back and you cannot see it.

First question is, am I doing this right to change my text color?  I want to change the textbox so once it is selected it stays a changed color.  I think this is correct.  But I am not sure if I should be setting Foreground or maybe a Font Style instead?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't change caret color so if you want your TextBox editable - you should keep the background white or otherwise light. Otherwise, controlling the look of your control in its various states is best done using VisualStateManager and that is easiest to manipulate using Blend.